# Tamron 18-200 lens

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, telephoto, tamron, superzoom

I am looking for a budget telephoto lens. The Canon 55-250 and Tamron 18-200 are both within my budget. I am slightly inclined towards getting the 18-200 because of the range it has. I looked up for reviews for this and couldn't find any good review with pictures from this lens. Can any one respond with quality of pics at 200mm ? Is it a good buy even though it doesn't have IS like the Canon 55-250?

Comment: Depending on the type of photography you do, the IS (or VC, Tamron's equivalent) feature is likely to me of greater value to you than marginal differences in image quality.

Comment: There is also the ef-s 18-200 with image stabilization which you could consider.

Comment: See the photozone.com website for reviews: [Tamron AF 18-200mm f/3.5-6.3 Di II LD Aspherical (IF) XR macro](http://www.photozone.de/canon-eos/292-tamron-af-18-200mm-f35-63-di-ii-ld-aspherical-if-xr-macro-test-report--review) and [Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS](http://www.photozone.de/canon-eos/411-canon_55250_456is_50d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't really need to be able to shoot wide with the same lens, then you'll generally get much better quality from a lens with narrower zoom range. To get a ~10x zoom range like the 18-200 compromises have to be made.

The Canon lens has a smaller zoom range, yet more reach and has stabilisation so is a better option on paper, however I've never used it so don't know how it performs in the real world.

Both lenses are designed for APS-C sensors only, if are thinking of upgrading to full frame you might want to consider a full frame lens, as in the telephoto range there is little weight penalty for the larger image circle.